# How to print list items which contain new line?

Tags: python

These commands:

```
l = ["1\n2"]    
print(l)
```

print

```
['1\n2']
```

I want to print

```
['1
2']
```

Is it possible when we generate the list outside of the `print()` command?

Comment: May I ask, what's wrong with this question?

Comment: I didn't downvote. You can improve the question by stating explicitly what you want, e.g.: I'd like to get the print (repr) output, but string literals should contain a newline character instead of `\n`. Alternatively you can give more examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first attempt:

```
l = ["1\n2"]
print(repr(l).replace('\\n', '\n'))
```

The solution above doesn't work in tricky cases, for example if the string is `"1\\n2"` it replaces, but it shouldn't. Here is how to fix it:

```
import re
l = ["1\n2"]
print(re.sub(r'\\n|(\\.)', lambda match: match.group(1) or '\n', repr(l)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Only if you are printing the element itself (or each element) and not the whole list:

```
>>> a = ['1\n2']
>>> a
['1\n2']
>>> print a
['1\n2']
>>> print a[0]
1
2
```

When you try to just print the whole list, it prints the **string representation** of the list. Newlines belong to individual elements so get printed as newlines only when print that element. Otherwise, you will see them as `\n`.

Comment: This actually does not put the element in a list like format, as shown in the OP's example.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use this, if you have more than one element

```
>>> test = ['1\n2', '3', '4\n5']
>>> print '[{0}]'.format(','.join(test))
[1
2,3,4
5]
```

Comment: Please post the input that you are passing to the above line.

Comment: @DSblizzard - You must be running a pretty old version of Python.  Such older versions require that you explicitly number the format fields.  Replace `'[{}]'` with `'[{0}]'` to fix the problem.

Comment: And what Python version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = ["1\n2"]
print("['{}']".format(s[0]))
=> ['1
   2']
```

Comment: Downvoter: care to comment? the input and the output in my answer are _exactly_ as in the question, so what's wrong?

Comment: I didnt downvote, but `print("['{}']".format(*s))` looks better, no?

Comment: @thefourtheye not necessarily, we'd need to see more sample inputs to tell if that would work.