# python prints out "\n" in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a project in Python where I want to string a list and print it out. The problem is that if I try to include `\n` to print in a new line the program straight out prints `\n` like this:

```
number_list = ["1\n", "2\n", "3\n"]
print(str(number_list))
```

**output**

```
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n']
```

**wanted output**

```
['1
', '2
', '3
']
```

How can I make the output like over when the list is stringed?

Comment: OK, well the only question here is why you would expect that output, given that a single-quoted string cannot contain unescaped newline characters.

Comment: Well, this is how `str(number_list)` works, I guess? What's the question?

Comment: @kaya3 The number or type of quotes has nothing to do with it. `"""1\n""" == '1\n'` is True.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to print list items which contain new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847664/how-to-print-list-items-which-contain-new-line)

Comment: Sidenote, `str()` is redundant inside `print()`. `print()` applies `str()` to its arguments automatically.

Comment: That's just how list's \_\_str\_\_ function deals with it's internals.  If you want custom output, you have to write it.  For the most part, the str and repr of most internal types are written in such a way that they can be pasted back into the REPL to get the same thing back.  If it did what you proposed, you'd get a syntax error instead.

Comment: @KirkStrauser It is a syntax error for a single-quoted string to contain an unescaped newline. It is not a syntax error for a triple-quoted string to contain an unescaped newline, and this is one of the main reasons to write triple-quoted strings. Try copy/pasting the OP's expected result into a Python interpreter if you are not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```py
lst = ["1\n", "2\n", "3\n"]
print(repr(lst).replace(r'\n', '\n'))
```

Outputs:

```
['1
', '2
', '3
']
```